# JS Dice Roller - How can I total all dice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dice

**The Problem**

It's been a long time since I programmed. I'm designing a game, and first programming it in JS/HTML/CSS since that is what I'm familiar with. Here is a dice roller I'm building. It rolls dice properly so far, but I can't seem to grab a total of dice as they are rolled. I'm assuming the variable for total is improperly defined, or out of scope.

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="dice" class="dice">
  </div>
  <div id="diceTotal"></div>
  <button id="button">Roll Die</button>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 8 vw;
}

button {
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 6vw;
  width: 40vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: .5vw;
}

.die {
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  padding: 0vw;
  margin: .5vw;
  border: .1vw solid gray;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  font-size: 9vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS**

```
var tot;
do {
  var sides = parseInt(prompt("How many sides are on your die? ", "6"), 10);
} while (isNaN(sides) || sides < 1);
var dice = {
  sides: sides,
  roll: function() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
    return randomNumber;
  }
}

//Prints dice roll to the page

function printNumber(number) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.className = "die";
  var diceroll = document.createTextNode(number);
  span.appendChild(diceroll);
  document.getElementById('dice').appendChild(span);
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  var result = dice.roll();
  printNumber(result);
  var tot = result + tot;
  var printDiceTotal = "Total: " + tot;
  document.getElementById('diceTotal').innerHTML = printDiceTotal;
};
```

Here is the JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/itmadsen/pkgej3uh/2/

I know I'm missing something basic, and I'll be kicking myself over it after someone comes up with a solution.

Comment: `var tot = result + tot;`  What is the initial value of tot?  `var` is creating a new variable with that name.  If you want it to use the global `tot`, take off the var.

Comment: It should be 0.

Comment: "should be".  Not what I asked, :)

Comment: Yes. Your response helped. For some reason, while I had attempted something like this before, I kept coming up with NaN. There must have been another break in my earlier code, but cleaning it up and fixing the variable definition fixed it. Fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to assign zero as initial value to tot

```
var tot = 0;
```

Secondly, you're defining tot twice

```
var tot = result + tot;
```

should become

```
tot = result + tot;
```

Here's working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/entio/pkgej3uh/5/

Comment: Awesome. I came up with the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks!**

I fixed it. Perfect!

https://jsfiddle.net/itmadsen/pkgej3uh/7/

**JS**

```
var tot = 0;
do {
  var sides = parseInt(prompt("How many sides are on your die? ", "6"), 10);
} while (isNaN(sides) || sides < 1);
var dice = {
  sides: sides,
  roll: function() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
    return randomNumber;
  }
}

//Prints dice roll to the page

function printNumber(number) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.className = "die";
  var diceroll = document.createTextNode(number);
  span.appendChild(diceroll);
  document.getElementById('dice').appendChild(span);
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.onclick = function() {
  var result = dice.roll();
  printNumber(result);
  tot = result + tot;
  var printDiceTotal = "Total: " + tot;
  document.getElementById('diceTotal').innerHTML = printDiceTotal;
};
```